# How to test a nestjs service by passing in a ConfigService with custom values?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, launchdarkly

I've created a service, and the module for it looks like this:

**launchdarkly.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  providers: [LaunchdarklyService],
  exports: [LaunchdarklyService],
  imports: [ConfigService],
})
export class LaunchdarklyModule {}
```

(this service/module is to let the application use LaunchDarkly feature-flagging)

I'm happy to show the service-implementation if you'd like, but to keep this question shorter I skipped it. The important point is that this service imports the `ConfigService` (which it uses to grab the LaunchDarkly SDK key).

But how can I test the `Launchdarkly` service? It reads a key from `ConfigService` so I want to  write tests where `ConfigService` has various values, but after hours of trying I can't figure out how to configure `ConfigService` in a test.

Here's the test:

**launchdarkly.service.spec.ts**

```js
describe('LaunchdarklyService', () => {
  let service: LaunchdarklyService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [LaunchdarklyService],
      imports: [ConfigModule],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<LaunchdarklyService>(LaunchdarklyService);
  });

  it("should not create a client if there's no key", async () => {
    // somehow I need ConfigService to have key FOO=undefined for this test
    expect(service.client).toBeUndefined();
  });

  it("should create a client if an SDK key is specified", async () => {
    // For this test ConfigService needs to specify FOO=123
    expect(service.client).toBeDefined();
  });
})
```

I'm open for any non-hacky suggestions, I just want to feature-flag my application!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming the `LaunchdarklyService` needs the `ConfigService` and that is injected into the constructor, you can provide a mock variation of the `ConfigService` by using a [`Custom Provider`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) to give back the custom credentials you need. For example, a mock for your test could look like

```js
describe('LaunchdarklyService', () => {
  let service: LaunchdarklyService;
  let config: ConfigService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [LaunchdarklyService, {
        provide: ConfigService,
        useValue: {
          get: jest.fn((key: string) => {
            // this is being super extra, in the case that you need multiple keys with the `get` method
            if (key === 'FOO') {
              return 123;
            }
            return null;
          })
        }
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<LaunchdarklyService>(LaunchdarklyService);
    config = module.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
  });

  it("should not create a client if there's no key", async () => {
    // somehow I need ConfigService to have key FOO=undefined for this test
    // we can use jest spies to change the return value of a method
    jest.spyOn(config, 'get').mockReturnedValueOnce(undefined);
    expect(service.client).toBeUndefined();
  });

  it("should create a client if an SDK key is specified", async () => {
    // For this test ConfigService needs to specify FOO=123
    // the pre-configured mock takes care of this case
    expect(service.client).toBeDefined();
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! The `jest.spyOn(config, 'get').mockReturnValueOnce` results in `Error: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`, but the core `useValue:{get: ...` pattern works.

Comment: Oh whoops, forgot to add a line in the `beforeEach`. I'll make an edit for that

Comment: I was just wondering  we can't reach the actual ConfigService ?

Comment: @katmanco you could use the actual `ConfigService`, but I find using mocks more reliable for unit tests

Answer (score 7):

You can get a cleaner syntax using the `forFeature` method provided by ConfigModule.

It accepts an async function that needs to return an object (in your case, your Env object).

The advantage of using the `forFeature` method is that you can register a partial object so you won't need to worry about other variables (or doing a lot of ifs).

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forFeature(async () => ({
        ANY_KEY_YOU_WANT: 'Any_Value'
      }))
    ],
    providers: [AnyService]
  }).compile()

  service = moduleRef.get<AnyService>(AnyService)
})
```

Comment: This is the cleanest of the solutions because it doesn't break the `ConfigService` contract. The solutions that override `get` will break if/when `getOrThrow` is called.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of providing ConfigService you need to import the ConfigModule with mocked data.
As an example

```
imports: [CommonModule,ConfigModule.forRoot({
                ignoreEnvVars: true,
                ignoreEnvFile: true,
                load: [() => ({ IntersectionOptions: { number_of_decimal_places: '3' }})],
            })],
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by overwriting the ConfigService provider as follows:

```js
import { CONFIGURATION_TOKEN } from '@nestjs/config/dist/config.constants';
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class TestConfigService {
  private initialConfig: Record<string, any>;
  constructor(
    @Optional()
    @Inject(CONFIGURATION_TOKEN)
    private internalConfig: Record<string, any> = {},
  ) {
    this.initialConfig = internalConfig;
  }

  get(key: string, def: any) {
    const result = findByPath(this.internalConfig, key);
    return result || def;
  }

  set(key: string, val: any) {
    assignRawDataTo(this.internalConfig, { [key]: val });
  }

  reset() {
    this.internalConfig = this.initialConfig;
  }
}
```

The `findByPath` and `assignRawDataTo` are some utility functions to get and set data to the internalConfig.

Now you can setup your testing module as below:

```js
return Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [
                 () => import('./test.config').then((module) => module.default),
             ],
             isGlobal: true,
         }),
      ],
}).overrideProvider(ConfigService)
    .useClass(TestConfigService);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do resolve this:

1. When you're creating a testing module "import" the config module the same way it was imported in your application root module:
   For Example:

```
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({ isGlobal: true, ttl: 60000 }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: Configs, // imported from another file
      ignoreEnvFile: false,
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      envFilePath: [".env"],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [ConfigService],
})
  .overrideProvider(PinoLogger)
  .useValue({
    info: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(null)),
  })
  .compile();
```

2. Mock the config service if you do not have a huge list of ENV Variables

```
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [CacheModule.register({ isGlobal: true, ttl: 60000 })],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: configService,
      useValue: {
        get: jest.fn(() =>
          Promise.resolve({
            VARIABLE_NAME: VALUE,
          })
        ),
      },
    },
  ],
})
  .overrideProvider(PinoLogger)
  .useValue({
    info: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(null)),
  })
  .compile();
```